# Detect skin color from live camera preview android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, camera, color-detection

I am trying to build an app which can detect skin color of different parts of skin ( hand, forehead, cheeks ) regardless of lighting condition. I am able to do it using this [project](https://github.com/tvbarthel/CameraColorPicker/tree/master/CameraColorPicker/app/src) but its not taking care of lighting conditions. This is one of the [Iphone app](http://youtube.com/watch?v=dz5hLvjt9J8) which does that

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to do some image processing on your own, i would recommend to create a histogram for each face region of your image. As long as opencv is capable of detecting the face, you should be able to normalize the histogram in that region and take the color values of the normalized version.

Maybe you want to normalize all channels (R,G,B) separately to reduce influences of colored light.

Read here for further information on histograms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram

When you follow that way, I strongly recommend to take one face as a whole region to create the histogram(s) for.

[Edit]

Now that I know what you try to do, I think you can take the following approach:

As you can see, the user needs to tap the camera fore and back. As the image is lit by the backside-led of the phone, the histogram is indeed exactly what the creators of that app are creating. However, not from different pixels but from different samples of the same pixel using different lighting levels.

When you are very close to the skin, the camera will show you a nearly white image, that is, if you like, the "fixed point" for the histogram calculation.

Although I am not going to show direct code, I will try to explain the mathematical model:

- Define a "focus" region in your image. This region is the area you take into account when calculating your histogram. All other regions at the edge will be ignored.
- Take some samples (e.g. 3 seconds, 10 samples per second = 30 samples)
- create a histogram of each sample and add them together:

  - For each lightness-value (there are maximal 256 of them) count the number of pixels that match this value, add all samples together
  - Find out the highest and lowest value that has at least a `threshold` number of values (your "working" range if you like) and call them `histLow` and `histHigh`
  - Recalculate each pixel so that `pixel = (pixel-histLow) / (histHigh-histLow) * 255`
  - Constrain the pixel value to the range 0 - 255
  - Take the average color value the pixels around a narrower range (e.g. only the highest number of samples)

If you don't know how to multiply or add colors in RGB, that's where you should start with a different question.

Comment: Can you direct me to some example code? Check this video where this app is detecting the color https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz5hLvjt9J8

Comment: Maybe you should add this video link to your question to provide the information on what you are trying to do. Now I get what you try to achieve, that renders my answer mostly inaccurate. I am goint to change my answer accordingly.

Comment: sure. Waiting for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, i will try creating histogram by taking different samples and will get back to you. Also, they are using 5 sheets of white paper to calibrate the phone lighting condition. Do i have to consider this while applying the above logic ?

Comment: This is something that needs research on your own. You should play around a little bit with what you can do and how good your code is at dealing with deviations.

Comment: I have collected 30 (RGB values as sample) for same pixel from different height. Now , i didn't understood what does your first step means. Does it mean that i have to add all the 30 RGB values and get the average color out of all samples to execute the next steps?

Comment: Not exactly. Read the wikipedia article about a histogram. Each sample now is a bunch of pixels. Build a histogram over all pixels of all samples and then normalize them.

Comment: I thought we are collecting only one pixel per sample i.e RGB of 30 pixel  from different height.

Comment: A histogram is just a "fingerprint" of a bunch of pixels. Using only 1 pixel per frame is possible, but using a region of pixels in each frame is more accurate. Think about it this way: You create a huge bucket where you put all your pixels you want to calculate your histogram for. Now you take each frame and take some of those pixels (the highly interesting ones near the center) and throw them into your bucket. After you processed all frames, your bucket is now full of pixels and you start creating a histogram for all of them

Comment: Hi @ShashankAgarwal , Able to Find a success?